# How to put random numbers in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import sys, pygame
import random
pygame.init()

x=0.5
speed = [x, x]
size = width, height = 800, 600
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("intro_ball.gif")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

Sair = True

while Sair:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: Sair=False
    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
        x=random.uniform(0, 1)
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
        x=random.uniform(0, 1)

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    pygame.display.flip()

sys.exit()
```

I expected the ball to move and every time it hits the corner change velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the ball move, you've to use a variable for position wich can store floating point coordinates. The position is changed every frame depending on the speed. Finally the ball rectangle has to be updated with the position:

[image]

```py
pos = [0, 0]
while Sair:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: Sair=False

    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        x = random.uniform(0.1, 1)
        speed[0] = x if speed[0] < 0.0 else -x 

    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        x = random.uniform(0.1, 1)
        speed[1] = x if speed[1] < 0.0 else -x  

    pos[0] += speed[0]
    pos[1] += speed[1]
    ballrect.topleft = (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1]))

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Note, the coordinates of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) are integral values. If a positive floating point value which is less that 1 is added to an integral value, then the value doesn't change at all, because the result is truncated to to the integral part again.

```
int a = 1
a + 0.5 == 1
```

Ensure that the random velocity is always greater than 0.0. Generate a random velocity and change the `speed` dependent on the new direction:

e.g.

```py
x = random.uniform(0.1, 1)
speed[0] = x if speed[0] < 0.0 else -x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `speed[0] = random.uniform(0, 1)` instead of `x = random.uniform(0, 1)`. When you change `x` you're not changing the values inside the list `speed`. This is because integers are immutable, which means they cannot be changed. When you do `x = random.uniform(0, 1)` you're just creating a new integer and binding `x` to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 0,1 why not use random.random - It does the same thing. Random.uniform is for taking parameters other than 0 & 1.

You need to make the speed = the random number you are generating. The x is never set to the speed